# How many works of Robert Silverberg's were based on Asimov's stories?

Tags: inspiration, isaac-asimov, robert-silverberg

It's well known that Silverberg wrote novels based on some of Asimov's stories.

For example, [The Child of Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0330325795) was based off of [The Ugly Little Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ugly_Little_Boy), and [Nightfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_(Asimov_novelette_and_novel)) was based off the Asimov story of the same name.

How many other (if any) novels/books/other works did Silverberg base off of Asimov stories?

Comment: See also "https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2292/4918" Degree of collaboration between Asimov and Silverberg on Nightfall novel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Three total**.  Jenkins’ Guide tells about them.

1. [*Nightfall*](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book457.html) (1990 novel) based on [“Nightfall”](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story185.html) (1941 short story).
2. [*The Ugly Little Boy*](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book501.html) (1992 novel) based on [“The Ugly Little Boy”](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story289.html) (1958 short story).
3. [*The Positronic Man*](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book503.html) (1993 novel) based on [“The Bicentennial Man”](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story015.html) (1976 short story)

We know there are only three of these from [the Guide's description for *The Positronic Man*](http://www.asimovreviews.net/Books/Book503.html).

> This is a fitting final third to Silverberg’s novelizations of Asimov’s stories.

The descriptions of the other two books tells the same.